# Rails Generate Custom Rakefile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on a project that is migrating data from a customers old_busted DB into rails objects to be worked on later. Similarly, I need to convert these objects into a CSV and upload it to a neutral FTP (this is to allow a coworker to build the example pages through Sugar CRM). I've created rake files to do all of this, and it was successful. Now, I'm going to continue this process for each object that I create in rails (relative to the previous DB) and, best case, wanted these generated when I run `rake generate scaffold <object>`.

Here is my import rake:

```
desc "Import Clients from db"
task :get_busted_clients => [:environment] do

    @old_clients = Busted::Client.all

    @old_clients.each do |row|
        @client = Client.new();
        @client.client_id = row.NUMBER  

        @client.save
    end
end
```

Here is my CSV convert/FTP upload rake:

```
desc "Exports db's to local CSV and uploads them to FTP"
task :export_clients_CSV => [:environment] do
# Required libraries for CSV read/write and NET/FTP IO #
    require 'csv'
    require 'net/ftp'

# Pull all Editor objects into clients for reading #
    clients = Client.all

    puts "Creating CSV file for <Clients> and updating column names..."
# Open a new CSV file that uses the column headers from Client #
    CSV.open("clients.csv", "wb", 
                :write_headers => true, :headers => Client.column_names) do |csv|

        puts "--Loading each entry..."
        # Load all entries from Client into the CSV file row by row #
        clients.each do |client|
        # This line specifically puts the attributes in the rows WITH RESPECT TO#
        # THE COLUMNS
            csv << client.attributes.values_at(*Client.column_names)
        end

        puts "--Done loading each entry..."
    end

    puts "...Data populated. Finished bulding CSV. Closing File."
    puts "------------------------"

# Upload CSV File to FTP server by requesting new FTP connection, assigning credentials 
# and informing the client what file to look for and what to name it
    puts "Uploading <Clients>..."

    ftp = Net::FTP.new('192.168.xxx.xxx')
    ftp.login(user = "user", passwd = "passwd")
    ftp.puttextfile("clients.csv", "clients.csv")
    ftp.quit()

    puts "...Finished."
end
```

I ran `rake generate g get_busted` and put this in my `get_busted_generator.rb`:

```
class GetBustedGenerator < Rails::Generators::NamedBase
source_root File.expand_path('../templates', __FILE__)

    def generate_get_busted
        copy_file "getbusted.rake", "lib/tasks/#{file_name}.rake"
    end

end
```

After that, I got lost. I can't find anything on templating a rake file or the syntax included to do so.

Rails has been a recent endeavor and I may be overlooking something in terms of design of the solution to my problem.

TL;DR: Is templating a rake file a bad thing? Solution alternatives? If not, whats the syntax for generating either script custom to the object (or point me in the direction, please).

Comment: I couldn't even get sugar crm to install , instead opted for fat free crm . How did u went on to get it work , can u point me to a documentation or something to install suagr crm for rails ?